# Chaining of mapreduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I came across "chaining of mapreduce jobs." Being new to mapreduce, under what circumstances do we have to chain (I am assuming chaining means running mapreduce jobs one after the other sequentially) jobs?

And are there any examples that could help?

Answer (score 17):

Classical example of a job that has to be chained is a word count that outputs words sorted by their frequency.

You will need:

Job 1:

- input source mapper (emits word as a key, one as a value)
- aggregating reducer (aggregates word counts)

Job 2:

- key/value swapping mapper (makes frequency as a key, word as a value)
- implicit identity reducer (gets words sorted by frequency, does not have to be implemented)

Here is the example of mappers/reducers above:

```java
public class HadoopWordCount {


  public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, LongWritable> {

    private final static Text word = new Text();
    private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class KeyValueSwappingMapper extends Mapper<Text, LongWritable, LongWritable, Text> {

    public void map(Text key, LongWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      context.write(value, key);
    }
  }

  public static class SumReducer extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
    private LongWritable result = new LongWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
      long sum = 0;
      for (LongWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
}
```

Here is the example of the driver program.

It expects two arguments:

1. an input text file to count words in.
2. an output dir (should not pre-exist) - look for the output in {this dir}/out2/part-r-0000 file

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Path out = new Path(args[1]);

    Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job1.setJarByClass(HadoopWordCount.class);
    job1.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job1.setCombinerClass(SumReducer.class);
    job1.setReducerClass(SumReducer.class);
    job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job1.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
    job1.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(out, "out1"));
    if (!job1.waitForCompletion(true)) {
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf, "sort by frequency");
    job2.setJarByClass(HadoopWordCount.class);
    job2.setMapperClass(KeyValueSwappingMapper.class);
    job2.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    job2.setSortComparatorClass(LongWritable.DecreasingComparator.class);
    job2.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job2.setInputFormatClass(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path(out, "out1"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(out, "out2"));
    if (!job2.waitForCompletion(true)) {
      System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks much Yurgis. Let me go thru this sample. Kind regards.

Comment: Why do we have to have to set the OutputFormatClass for job1 and InputFormatClass for job2?  Without those statements, I'm getting a ClassCastException in the KeyValueSwappingMapper.  And I'm not sure exactly where that exception is being thrown.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you have to chain multiple map reduce jobs when your problem cannot fit in just one map reduce job.

A good example is to find a top 10 bought items, this can achieved by 2 jobs :

1. A map reduce job to find how many time each item is bought.
2. The second job, sort items based on number of times it was bought, and get top 10 items.

To get complete idea, job chaining generate intermidiate files that are written to, and read from disk, therefore it will decrease performance. **Try to avoid chaining jobs as possible**.

And [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#chaining) how to chain jobs.

Comment: Your link is now broken.